# wanting to cut out hidden println in java

Tags: java, println

```
int anzZeilen = 9;
    int anzZahlen = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {

        System.out.print("      ");

        for (int j = 1; j < anzZeilen; j++) {

            System.out.print("  ");

        }

        if (anzZahlen % 2 != 0) {

            for (int x = 1; x <= anzZahlen; x++) {

                System.out.print("  ");

                System.out.print(x + " ");

            }

        }

        System.out.println();
        anzZahlen++;
        anzZeilen--;

    }
```

my problem is that i am creating 9 new println, but i only want to  create a new line if the if-statement is true so i dont have that much space inbetween. how do i do that?

[my code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXItQ.png)

[my code with println inside the if block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87XOk.png)

Comment: What is the goal with the prints of spaces? Also the println is not currently in the if statement, so put it inside the if block statement after the inner for loop

Comment: Its code from another task where it needed a new line after every inner loop. I've already tried putting it there, but it destroys the pyramid that is supposed to come out

Comment: Can we see some correct example output? Hard to visualize

Comment: updated my post with pictures

Answer (score 0):

You could just maintain a single `StringBuilder` and append to it along the way, printing once only at the end:

```
int anzZeilen = 9;
int anzZahlen = 1;
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

for (int i=1; i <= 9; i++) {
    msg.append("      ");
    for (int j=1; j < anzZeilen; j++) {
        msg.append("  ");
    }

    if (anzZahlen % 2 != 0) {
        for (int x = 1; x <= anzZahlen; x++) {
            msg.append("  ").append(x).append(" ");
        }
    }

    msg.append("\n");
    anzZahlen++;
    anzZeilen--;
}

// now print the entire message, once
System.out.println(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but i thinks a bit too much since im at the very start of java and we're probably not supposed to solve it like this. Altough i will try it out i would like to have a solution that fits my java knowledge right now